# Source not found with debugging code in java

Tags: java, eclipse, breakpoints

I'm new in java ...I have this when used break point in the code

`source not found` .....> `Edit source look up path`

[image]

then i added src.zip of Jdk1.6.0_38 for rt.jar by windows>preferences>installedJRE>source attahchment of rt.jar

and got this after i returned to breakpoint
[image]

I'm on ubuntu 12.04 and eclipse Kepler

what can i do to solve this ?

Comment: it would be helpful if you can share your debug configuration

Comment: which part you need to share it ? you mean source tab or classpath or what ?

Comment: share your project structure and the class name for which you are getting `ClassNotFoundException`

Answer (score 0):

add the `source` (jar file which contains your class) in the debug configuration

`Debug as> Debug Configurations> Source > Add`

Comment: which source you mean ? the folder of the project ?or jar file ?