# source not found in java library

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm new to java and facing this problem while debugging code 
[image]

[image]

I found rt.jar when used external file but didn't work , Is that mean the file is corrupt or what ?

Comment: (Just a hint for next time, it would probably help to mention that you're using Eclipse on Ubuntu.)

Comment: sorry , i'll do that now , thanks

Comment: Also, isn't this the same question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27718194/source-not-found-with-debugging-code-in-java?

Comment: yes that's right , i forgot it but i reviewed it now with no answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to attach src.zip as the source (probably in `/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64`). If you don't have src.zip, make sure the openjdk-6-source package is installed.

Comment: thanks for helping , i found it but with size 32 bit and when i tried to attach it , i got that src.zip doesn't exist but i've another question is that error will affect on the code ?

Comment: As I said, try installing the openjdk6-source package using the package manager. Then try attaching it as the source for rt.jar.

Comment: attach src.zip or just rt.jar ?

Comment: what about the other part of the question , can you help ?  " is that error will affect on the code ? "

Comment: I don't understand that part of the question, could you re-phrase it? If you mean, will not attaching the source affect how your code is run, the answer is no -- but it will prevent you from using the debugger.